# Multiple a functions with multiple arguments with purrr

Tags: r, function, purrr

I was able to implement a way to iterate the combination of arguments to a single function:

```
a <- seq(1, 5, 1)
b <- rep(10, 15, 1)

foo <- function(a, b){ a + b}
foo2 <- function(a, b) {a * b}

result <- invoke_map_dbl(foo, cross2(a, b))
```

However, I have not been able to iterate those arguments over two functions. I would like to do this:

```
result <- invoke_map_dbl(list(foo, foo2), cross2(a,b))
```

Is it possible?

Comment: what output do you want ?

Comment: In this example I expect one vector. My intend is to apply to a function that produces a data frame, & bind all the results into one data frame.

Comment: you have nice reproducible inputs, why don't you lay out the exact output you expect as well ?

Answer (score 3):

The problem might be trying to force a list output to `dbl`.  Don't you just need...

```
invoke_map(list(foo,foo2), a=a, b=b)

[[1]]
[1] 11 12 13 14 15

[[2]]
[1] 10 20 30 40 50
```

You could `unlist` to get a single vector, if that is what you want.

Looking at this again, I notice that you are just defining `b=10`, which looks wrong.  So this probably doesn't do what you are asking for, but you will need to be more specific with your question.